# Prototype Multi-Event Observation for Multi-Elements

Tags: prototypejs

```
['element1','element2','element3'].each(function(e){
    Event.observe(e, 'click', function(event){ ... });
    Event.observe(e, 'blur', function(event){ ... });
    Event.observe(e, 'mousedown', function(event){ ... });
    Event.observe(e, 'mouseover', function(event){ ... });
    });
```

Is there a way to reduce this so that I can do

```
['element1','element2','element3'].each(function(e){
    Event.observe(e, ev, function(event){
        switch(e){
            switch (ev)
            }
        });
    });
```

?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [invoke](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/enumerable/invoke)?

```
var elements = $$('#element1','#element2','#element3');

elements.invoke('observe', 'click', function(e) {...});
elements.invoke('observe', 'blur', function(e) {...});
elements.invoke('observe', 'mousedown', function(e) {...});
elements.invoke('observe', 'mouseover', function(e) {...});
```

Comment: I was thinking on these lines :
Event.observe(e, 'click blur mousedown mouseover', function(e)
And then doing switch(e.type) to check for the event.
In jQuery we can do : 
$('#id, #id2, id3').bind('click blur mousedown mouseover',function(e){ ... });